# Get XML from String (not file)

Tags: xml, string, powershell

I have a PowerShell script:

```
$xmlString="<root>
        <section>
            <node id='1'>AAA</node>
            <node id='2'>BBB</node>
            <node id='3'>CCC</node>
        </section>
    </root>"

$xml = New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlDocument
$content = $xml.LoadXml($xmlString)
```

Value of `$content` is `null`

Inner Exception in `$xml` variable is `<Error retrieving property - ArgumentException>`

I have checked whether string starts with `[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetPreamble()` but it does not.

Can you please tell, what it is correct way to convert such string to XML?

Comment: You're just misunderstanding how `LoadXML()` works. The imported XML is in the variable `$xml`, not `$content`. The method doesn't return anything, so `$content` is empty.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I added your follow up to my answer :)

Comment: @Paxz Cheater ;þ

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers wanna make it an own answer? :D I can still roll back ;)

Comment: @Paxz Nah, I'm good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can directly cast the string to `XmlDocument` like this:

```
[xml]$xmlString="<root>
        <section>
            <node id='1'>AAA</node>
            <node id='2'>BBB</node>
            <node id='3'>CCC</node>
        </section>
    </root>"
```

If you want to keep the format of the variable, you can ofc just do it like this:

```
$xmlString="<root>
        <section>
            <node id='1'>AAA</node>
            <node id='2'>BBB</node>
            <node id='3'>CCC</node>
        </section>
    </root>"

[xml]$content = $xmlString
```

---

To follow up on @AnsgarWiechers comment, if you really want to use `LoadXML`, this is how it should look:

```
$xmlString=
"<root>
        <section>
            <node id='1'>AAA</node>
            <node id='2'>BBB</node>
            <node id='3'>CCC</node>
        </section>
</root>"

$xml = New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlDocument
$xml.LoadXml($xmlString)
```

`LoadXml` will load a value from the given string to the `$xml` variable that calls the method.

It doesn't return any value, but saves it to `$xml`.

Answer (score 1):

`ConvertFrom-Xml` is what you need!

It's available from the PowerShell Gallery as part of [Avande.CoolFunctions](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Avanade.CoolFunctions/1.3.5)

```
$xmlString = @"
<root>
    <section>
        <node id='1'>AAA</node>
        <node id='2'>BBB</node>
        <node id='3'>CCC</node>
    </section>
</root>
"@

$xmlString | ConvertFrom-Xml
```

Comment: As far as I know, `ConvertFrom-Xml` is not a powershell built-in cmdlet. However, simply casting it with `[xml]` like @Paxz did is the way to go.

Comment: You're right @Theo ! I've added a link to the source of the CmdLet to my answer.